# Proving an identity of the Möbius function and Euler’s totient function product

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Could anyone kindly help me to prove that
$$
\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \varphi(d) = 0
$$
for all *even* integers $ n \geq 2 $, where $ \mu $ is the Möbius function and $ \varphi $ is Euler’s totient function? Thank you!

Comment: How are $\varphi(k)$ and $\varphi(2k)$ related?

Comment: @DanielFischer if 'k' is prime φ(2k)=φ(2)φ(k)

Comment: Not quite right, that doesn't hold for $k = 2$. But we're heading in the right direction. What is $\varphi(2)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer φ(2) = 1. Is it right?

Comment: It is. So where are we with the relation between $\varphi(k)$ and $\varphi(2k)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer they are equal if 'k' is prime

Comment: Not always. Under which circumstances are the two equal (and what is the relation between the two if they are not equal, but that isn't strictly needed for this task)?

Comment: @DanielFischer They are equal when gcd(2, k) = 1. Correct?

Comment: Correct. And the relation between $\mu(k)$ and $\mu(2k)$?

Comment: μ(k) = μ(2k) if k is prime and it equals 1. Isn't it?

Comment: Don't focus so much on primes. (And no, that's not correct. When is $\mu(m) = 1$, when $\mu(m) = -1$ and when $\mu(m) = 0$?)

Comment: @DanielFischer μ(n) = 1 if n is a square-free positive integer with an even number of prime factors.
μ(n) = −1 if n is a square-free positive integer with an odd number of prime factors.
μ(n) = 0 if n has a squared prime factor.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh!!! μ(k) = — μ(2k). Right?

Comment: Well, unless $k\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer can you explain me 'lab bhattacharjee' solution below? How he have moved from sum to multiplication?

Comment: Do you know what a multiplicative function is?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, for example μ(ab) = μ(a)μ(b) whenever a and b are coprime

Comment: Better call the function $f$, since $\mu$ is usually a specific one. Yes. Now, two facts about multiplicative functions are used in lab's answer. 1. If $f$ and $g$ are multiplicative functions, then $f\cdot g$ is also multiplicative. That one is very easy to see. Since $\mu$ and $\varphi$ are multiplicative, it shows that $f = \mu\cdot\varphi$ is also multiplicative. And 2. If $f$ is multiplicative, then $g\colon n\mapsto \sum\limits_{d\mid n} f(d)$ is also multiplicative. So we have $$g(n) = \prod_{k=1}^r g(p_k^{a_k})$$ if $n = \prod_{k=1}^r p_k^{a_k}$. And $g(p^a)$ is easily determined.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you. Think, its clear for me now

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \varphi(d) $$

$$=\prod_{\text{prime }p\mid n}[\mu(1)\phi(1)+\mu(p)\phi(p)+0]$$ (using the definition of Möbius [function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function))

$$=\prod_{\text{prime }p\mid n}[1-(p-1)]$$

Comment: Is it equal 0 (zero)? Why?

Comment: @Meiblorn, If $n$ is even, one of the primes is $2$

Comment: And what means 0 in sum?

Comment: @Meiblorn, Please follow the link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since the $\mu$ function is zero over non-squarefree numbers, assuming that $\omega(n)=k$ and the primes dividing $n$ are $p_1,\ldots,p_k$, we have:

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\varphi(d) = \sum_{I\subset\{1,\ldots,k\}}(-1)^{|I|}\prod_{i\in I}(p_i-1)=(-1)^k\prod_{j=1}^{k}(p_j-1)\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(1+\frac{-1}{p_i-1}\right)$$
so:
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\varphi(d) = (-1)^{\omega(n)}\prod_{p\mid n}(p-2).$$
Obviously, if $n$ is even then the RHS is zero.